# Sequence next value in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to use the same sequence number across multiple select statements 
in SQL form to eventually use it as a PK insert in a table and tie multiple records together.

So far, I can only select the NEXTVAL from dual:

```
SELECT TEST_SEQ.NEXTVAL AS SEQ FROM DUAL;
```

However, when I include the sequence into a multiple column select, I get sequence not allowed here error.

```
SELECT col1, co2, col3, (select TEST_SEQ.NEXTVAL) SEQ
FROM table;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use a sub-select:

```
SELECT col1, co2, col3, TEST_SEQ.NEXTVAL as SEQ
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to select the next value from sequence object, you can use this SQL statement.

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[seq_Vehicles] AS NextVehicleId
```

If you want to select multiple next values from SQL Sequence, you have to loop calling the above SQL statement and save the "next value" got in a storage.

You can loop using (while loop) or by (cursor).

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select SEQ_tablename.NEXTVAL from DUAL;
```

Answer (score 1):

In tsql use Next Value for dbo.seqYourSequence to retrieve a value